# A combination of two tables to fill a distance D algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Assume two type of tables, the shorter is X and the longer is Y. A combination of two types of tables are aligned to fill a distance D. find the optimum combination to keep the remaining empty distance is as small as possible. the first priority is to minimize the empty distance the second priority is to minimize the number of used tables

ex Input: X = 3 element, Y = 5 elements, D = 24 empty elements 
The optimum combination is: 3 of X type tables, 3 of type Y tables , Remaining empty = 0

my solution based on while loop and if-else statements
 R=24
 X=3
 Y=5
 N#X=N#Y=0
 while(R>X):
   if R%Y==0:
      N#Y=R/Y
      R=0
   else if R % X == 0:
     N#X=R%X
      R=0
but not optimal solution

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldbXD.png)

Comment: This is very hard to understand.  What does "aligned yo fill a distance D" mean?  What is the "remaining empty distance"?  What are TX, TY, RD?  Finally, what is your question?  Please add some details to make this plainer.

Comment: i have table D consists of as example 24 cell
i have another tables x,y  
x -3 values 
y 5 values
i need copy x or y or both fill  but the first priority is to minimize the empty cells the second priority is to minimize the number of used tables

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't make any sense of that.  " i have another tables x,y x -3 values y 5 values i need copy x or y or both fill" isn't English.  Try to write short sentences, and give a full example.  Please respond by editing the question, not writing more comments.